# How to open an Activity from Slideout in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I downloaded from Android.com an example of [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) (I want to make a Slideout)

but, in that example when I click in a item of the slideout, this will open an image, so, How can i open an Activity instead of an image?

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on press ( Button press or whatever is relavant to you)

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Currentactivity.this,Activitytoopen.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Here:

1) Currentactivity.this should be replaced with the class name you are currently on.

2) Activitytoopen.class should be replaced with the activity name you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this codes

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```